# Squashing commits on Gitlab BEFORE merge

Tags: git, gitlab, squash

I got couple commits on Gitlab inside my branch and want to squash them in one BEFORE merge(!important). When I `try git rebase -i` the terminal responds with `error: nothing to do`. How can I make it work?

Comment: provide the base branch as an additional argument.... you could use `@{u}` as a placeholder for the upstream branch (if it is set).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get it done with a one-liner setup as an alias to not have to *do* anything:

```
git reset --soft $( git merge-base @{u} HEAD ); git commit
```

This *should* open the terminal window so you can provide the text for the commit.... turn that into a script and then you could get it to handle the comment (by capturing additional parameters) in a single shot and so on.

Adding a check to make sure that the working tree is clean before running that would be a nice addition.

Comment: git reset --soft HEAD~2
git commit
git push --force

this is what worked for me

Comment: It's the same concept. Instead of using a fixed number of commits to reset to, I am looking for the diversion point.

Answer (score 0):

before start rebase make sure that you are in project directory that .git folder exist there
after it use:  `git rebase --interactive HEAD~N`

"N" that how many commit you like squash

another solution is use gitlab interface for squash
you can use squash button on merge request if enabled it
you can enable it from setting-> merge request -> Squash commits when merging